# How can I force a hybrid 64/32bit application to install as a 32bit software in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, installation, 64-bit, 32-bit

Well the title says it all, when I install this application it installs in its 64 bit mode which is buggy for me, but the 32 bit mode worked perfectly on my previous computer, is there anyway to have it install as a 32bit software?

Comment: Nice question! I don't have an answer, but I think that there's one thing which needs commenting: Currently there are almost no 64 bit applications which are 64 bit because they don't **have** to be 64 bit. Are you sure that the 32 bit version can work at all on a 64 bit operating system?

Comment: What operating system are you using? Windows and Mac OS X can handle mixed binaries almost perfectly (unless some program needs to load some plug-in that is compiled for a different architecture). Linux may require you to use the correct architecture binary, but you should be able to get it quite easily.

Comment: What application? I suppose its installer might have some command-line switches, but I doubt there is a generic answer to your question as-is.

Comment: What application? What bugs? Your question is too vague to answer without more information.

Comment: Thank you guys, I'm on Windows 7. I thought there might be a simple compatibility mode like switch I could pull, but I guess not.

Comment: If you can figure out where in Windows the installer looks to check for bit version, you could change that info to 32bit temporarily to fool it. Might take some detective work using Process Monitor...http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645

Comment: You realize that this software program being buggy might have nothing to do with the software?  Most 64-bit programs are simply 32-bit programs in a 64-bit wrapper which allows them to take advantage of the higher memory limits.  The bugginess that you are experience may be a symptom of something else entirely.